# Incluir Option/Select na pesquisa

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde galera, gostaria de incluir o option para minha pesquisa, já tentei assim:

```
var $search = $("#search").on('input, option',function(){
        $btns.removeClass('active');
        var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
        $('.box').show().not(function(){
            return matcher.test($(this).find('.name, .sku, .local').text())
        }).hide();
    })
```

Mas não obtive êxito.

Comment: Para quando você mudar ele automaticamente pesquisar?

Comment: Isso mesmo, o jeito que estou usando ele obtêm o resultado do option de uma database, mas ele aparece para o usuário selecionar qual ele quer que seja pesquisado.

Comment: Tenta assim: `$("#search").on('change',function(){ //corpo })`

Comment: Vc que pegar o valor de um select?

Answer (score -1):

Troque esta linha

```
var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
```

por

```
var matcher = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
```

e a linha

```
var $search = $("#search").on('input, option',function(){
```

por

```
$('#search').on('change', function () {
```

Comment: Não resolveu o teu problema, @EvertonGouveia?